# MDB transaction does not rollback email on timeout

Tags: timeout, jms, rollback, message-driven-bean

I have an MDB that listens on a queue. Whenever it recieves a message, it will forward execution to a stateless session bean which has a lot of logic, updates etc. Here is the flow of logic/call chain.

queue->mdb->session bean->session bean->email->logging

The end result is an email and subsequent logging.

By default, the MDB transaction is managed by container and its time out is 30 seconds.

However, whenever timeout is reached, it throws timeout exception and retries the message, but the nested transaction and its processes are not rolled back(from session bean). As a result, multiple emails go out because of the retry but all the logging is rolled back (from session beans) EXCEPT for what is logged from the MDB itself

Shouldnt all the transactions being called from the MDB rollback including the mdb logging and especially the emails?

The session beans all have default transaction type as 'required'.

I also explicitly set the TransactionManagement type as CONTAINER with the TransactionType as REQUIRED. Emails still go out. Logging from session beans rollback but retry occurs.

I then set the TransactionType as REQUIRES_NEW. Emails still go out. Logging from session beans rollback but retry DOESNT occur.

what setting do I put to make sure the ENTIRE transaction started by the MDB and any transactions called from it, get rolled back AND retry occurs?

I do not want to use bean managed transactions because I want the retry on failure to occur.

My application server is weblogic 10.3 with ejb 3 spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email resource is not transactional, so ditch the mdb timeout and have your email sender rely on the email transport timeout, at which point, call TX setrollback only. The tx will rollback, the message will be redelivered and your email **may** only be sent on a successful retry. The outcome of email transport timeout may not be deterministic.

Comment: I dont understand what you said. My problem is that be it an MDB timeout or any other exception that gets thrown AFTER the email is sent, transactional updates such as logging to a db table gets rolled back but the email still goes out. How does setting timeout on the mail transport prevent the email from going out in this case?

Comment: Setting the timeout on the transport gives you your best likelihood of keeping your DB and *actual* emails sent in synch. Having the MDB timeout has no effect on the email send, so eliminate it. When you get a timeout on the transport, the email *probably* did not make it out the door, so rollback the TX. If you get a handshake from the email transport, then the email definitely made it as far as the SMTP server, so commit the TX. Once you call the email send, there is virtually no deterministic way to know for certain if it actually made it out the door (when an exception occurs).

Comment: Nicholas, you are right. There is no way, as far as I know, to prevent the mail from going out once it is successfully sent, via JavaMail API methods. I thought there would be some way to handle this via XA Resource managers so that the mail gets sent out once commit occurs, but no luck there. Thanks.